# Trackpad seems a slightly sporadic with certain things, ie auto hide dock

Tags: touchpad

I'm slightly concerned because I'm a new ubuntu user and the trackpad just feels a little clunky sometimes. For example, when doing a 2-finger selection it will freeze sometimes, and when dock is set to auto hide, sometimes I have a bit of trouble getting it to re-appear with the pointer, I have to move the pointer down to the dock a few times to get it to appear when I have a window open. Then sometimes the trackpad seems perfectly smooth and the dock on auto hide responds just fine to the pointer. Any ideas?